# Can you split tables in a View during a foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a meal plan project, and for visual presentation's sake, I was wondering if during a foreach loop each table with a unique MealPlan_ID could have a break (a separation) between each table with presented data?

Currently, each new meal plan that is generated just adds to the one table.

The View:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            ID
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Recipe Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Day
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            View More
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
    @foreach ($data as $var)
        <tr>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->Recipe_ID}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->recipe_name}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->Day}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm font-medium">
                <a href="recipeinformation/{{$var->Recipe_ID}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900 mb-2 mr-2">More</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I have two database tables that affect the populating of the table, the MealPlan Table and the Recipe Table.

Index method in **MealPlanDisplayController**:

```
public function index(){
    
$currentuserid = Auth::id();

$data = Recipe::join('mealplan_main', 'mealplan_main.Recipe_ID', '=', 'recipe.id')->where('mealplan_main.user_id', '=', $currentuserid)->get(['mealplan_main.Recipe_ID', 'recipe.recipe_name', 'mealplan_main.Day']);

return view('MealPlanDisplay.index', compact('data'));
```

Is it possible to split the table every time a new Meal Plan is generated with a new Meal Plan ID? If not, what is a better way to present the data other than a table, since I would like to visually present the meal plans separate from each other (as a user can have multiple meal plans)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case `$data` is a collection, so you can use [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby)

```
$grouped = $data->groupBy('Meal_Plan_ID');

/*
[
    1 => [ /* data */ ], //Recepies for meal plan 1
    2 => [ /* data */ ], //Recepies for meal plan 2
]
*/
```

Then in HTML

```
@foreach ($grouped as $mealPlan)
        <!-- Init of new table or set pace -->
    @foreach ($mealPlan as $recepie)
        <!-- Recepie columns -->
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```